# Which USA visa do I need as a solo artist to work in the USA (dance performer)

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas

I  have a dream about coming to the USA after my studies at the end of 2021 and work as a dancer for a few weeks/months.

A short info: I am a freelance dancer from Germany. By dancing I mean gogodancing(no strip!)/showdance/different props like hula hoops, entertainment, I also create my own small shows.

Now the question: What kind of visa do I need to come to the US and be able to work there as a dancer? Which visa is the best for my purpose?

In case its important:

- I have a newspaper article about me (German language)
- Dance in a German crime series (Soko Potsdam) and
- Perform in a famous club (Club Matrix Berlin).
- I have  won 2 talent/dance competitions from the university.

I´m just finishing my studies (I could extend it if a student status is better for the visa).

Comment: I remember seeing an identical/almost identical question three or four days ago, but Search doesn't bring it up. Does anyone else remember this?

Comment: It was asked in Travel Stack Exchange. @DavidSupportsMonica

Comment: Thanks! Glad I wasn’t hallucinating.